# Maven execute a plugin twice, once in an "always active" profile, and again in a conditionally run profile?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm trying to run a plugin once in an "always active" maven profile, and again in a conditionally executed profile.  When the conditional profile is run, the plugin in the "always on" profile doesn't execute.  However, when executing maven with just the "always active" profile, the plugin runs just fine.

Here is a sample of my pom.xml

```
<profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>!doNoEverSetThisPropertyThisProfileShouldAlwaysBeActive</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>                    
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>antCopyResources</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    ...
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
</profile>

<profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>prodTokenReplace</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    ...
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
</profile>
```

For example, if I invoke maven like:

```
mvn clean compile
```

The antrun plugin in the default profile runs just fine.

However, if I invoke maven like:

```
mvn -P prod clean compile
```

Only the antrun plugin in prod runs.

```
mvn -P prod help:active-profiles

Active Profiles for Project 'projectname':

The following profiles are active:

 - default (source: pom)
 - prod (source: pom)
```

Comment: Can you afford running it in different phases?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but it might help others.

I have a similar case that I solved by putting the common (activeByDefault) part of the execution outside of the **profiles** part and in the main **build** section.

This way, the build will always run the main build's antrun and depending on the condition, the antrun in the relevant profile.

Based on your initial example:

```
<build>
      <plugins>                    
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>antCopyResources</id>
                       <phase>process-resources</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>run</goal>
                       </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
              ...
         </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
   <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>prodTokenReplace</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    ...
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
   </profile>
<profiles>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave default as-is, and copy the ant-run plugin configuration from default into prod so you end up with two plugin configurations in prod, like:

```
<profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>antCopyResources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                ...
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prodTokenReplace</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                ...
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: I might have to do that, but it seems quite unnecessary.  I trimmed my pom down quite a bit, basically each profile is a build profile for a particular environment (dev, qa, prod, etc.).  All the plugins I have in default should be run in addition to whichever build profile is selected.